# ReSharper / Visual Studio add <inheritdoc/> to all undocumented inherited functions and properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

With ReSharper you can have it add `<inheritdoc/>` to inherited functions and properties. I'm needing a ton of these added to currently undocumented functions but I don't want to have to add these one by one. Is there any way to have ReSharper or Visual Studio add that to all undocumented AND inherited functions and properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided upon using Regex replace. In case someone is interested, my solution:

```
(^\s*$)(\n)\s*public override
```

to

```
\r\n        /// <inheritdoc />\r\n        public override
```